# Include files and directories in Kotlin Jar file on the command line

Tags: java, kotlin, jar, kotlinc

How can I include resources in a kotlin jar file created on the command line? With java I can just do

```
jar cfm File.jar manifest.txt File.class resource.txt resourceDirectory
```

In Kotin on the command line we can use

```
kotlinc -d File.jar file.kt
```

to create a jar file, but I cannot add non kotlin files into the jar the same way I can with Java.  Does anyone know if this is possible on the command line without gradle/maven and how can I do it?

I'd also like to be able to include the Kotlin runtime in the jar

Comment: Use `-d someDirectory` and then create a jar with the jar command?

Comment: Keep in mind jar files are just zip files, so you can always use zip command line tools if you are stuck.